# Allocation failed - process out of memory while npm install

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, gulp

I have installed `nodejs` and `npm` in my `aws` server and there were no issues. But when I tried to install `bower`, I got a memory allocation error. I was able to fix it by disabling the progress bar by

```
sudo npm set progress=false
```

But i'm getting

> Allocation failed - process out of memory error

on `npm install`. I tried `npm cache clean`, but the same error exists.

Comment: missused backtick made formatting bad

Comment: fixed some more formatting and grammar

Comment: Have you considered that it ran out of RAM?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here appears to be pretty self explanatory, Node is running out of memory. I have previously ran into this issue on a machine with only 600MB of ram, I'd suggest increasing the instance size to something with over 1GB of RAM and trying again.